# How can I collect this orb container thing in Archaea, Cave III?

Tags: steamworld-dig

[image]

How can I mine that block in the "II" cave of the second area? It's late game (I'm about to enter the "III" cave of the third area) and I still can't figure out how I could get myself some more blue-thingies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Brjánn at image & form here. Can you reach the area at the top right in the shot from above, so that you can dig down? :)

The orbs appear a little here and there, and they are randomly placed. I still haven't seen any "impossible" orbs or gems though. Good luck!

Comment: For the skeptical, [this is really him](https://twitter.com/BrjannSigur/status/512872632359084032). :D

Answer (score 1):

In this spot, you want to jump on the solid platform to the left of the area and bounce a stick of dynamite off the spring below.  You will open a secret area to the right that you can then dig down from.  It might take a few sticks of dynamite to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

There's a weak dirt block a little to right against the wall.   Mushroom bounce and touch that block and it will break leading to a passage that goes above the orb in question.  Happy hunting!

Answer (score 0):

I did the loaded punch and had him shoot it diagnol at the orb. Took a couple of shots but it worked